# How to know if the HTTP request comes from an WebDav client?

Tags: http, server, user-agent, webdav

I'm creating a web file manager and it was recently suggested to me to implement WebDav on it and I thought it is a really nice idea.

I thought about keeping the webdav in a separate URL like `/webdav` but now I'm thinking about keeping both the web interface I created and the webdav server at the same URL.

In order to know if I should provide an HTML page or the file I need to know if it is being accessed from a browser OR from a webdav server. How should I know that? Is the User-Agent enough?

If so, which user-agents should I treat as a WebDav client?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to look at the Accepts Header, but I am not sure about your question.  Why would you need to provide different responses for the DAV clients on things like GET.  If a browser asks for an HTML page or a DAV Client asks for an HTML, they should get HTML, no?  Or do you mean something browser asks for `foo.ph`p, they get html, DAV Client asks for `foo.php` they get source code?

Comment: The last one @Doon! The web interface is able to edit files, delete files and everything else. It's a file manager + editor. That's why I need different responses for GET. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use something like Authenticated vs unauthenticated in order to determine, but as @evert says don't do this.    also reading the DAV specs (RFC 2518) (http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html)

> In the absence of distributed authoring capabilities, it is acceptable to have no mapping of source resource(s) to the URI
>   namespace. In fact, preventing access to the source resource(s) has
>   desirable security benefits. However, if remote editing of the source
>   resource(s) is desired, the source resource(s) should be given a
>   location in the URI namespace. This source location should not be one
>   of the locations at which the generated output is retrievable, since
>   in general it is impossible for the server to differentiate requests
>   for source resources from requests for process output resources. There
>   is often a many-to-many relationship between source resources and
>   output resources.

the Important part here is

> This source location should not be one of the locations at which the >generated output is retrievable, since in general it is impossible for the >server to differentiate requests for source resources from requests for >process output resources

Comment: Hello again @Doon! So, as I said to @Evert, I think that using 
`http://localhost/folder/file.txt` and `http://localhost/webdav/folder/file.txt` will be a best practice. The first one for the web interface and the second one for Dav clients. Am I right?

Comment: yes as long the are unique URIs you should be good (names don't matter, just uniqueness)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Using a `User-Agent` to determine what behavior your server is going to exhibit is in general a bad idea, and it's also a bad idea for WebDAV. Some clients use more than 1 user agent, some clients use pretty generic (curl) ones, and others don't supply one at all. It makes your system brittle, prone to error and non-standard because I can't just build a WebDAV client and expect it to work unless I mimic one of the accepted user agents.

That being said... you might still be able to get away with it avoiding the `User-Agent`. WebDAV uses a `PROPFIND` HTTP method which you can use to accurately determine if a WebDAV client is connecting.

However, it still uses `GET` and `PUT` as well to fetch and store files, and you *must* build the system in a strict WebDAV hierarchy. If your existing url structure already 1:1 matches the filesystem hierarchy, this might work.

In some ways you are just building a WebDAV server then that just has html-indexes for collections, which is actually somewhat common.

Lastly, consider using a library instead of rolling your own.

Source: I'm the author of a [popular webdav framework](http://sabre.io/).

Comment: Hello @Evert! Thanks for your answer. I'm using Go and its own webdav library. Right now, the directory structure is exactly like the file system. But I also want to show html when you're requesting a file for the browser so the user can edit it right on the browser (using my interface).

Comment: One solution might be keeping the web dav server in a separate URL and make the Ajax requests to that path.

Comment: Example: `http://localhost/folder/file.txt` would show my web interface with an editor and all of those things. But if you access `http://localhost/webdav/folder/file.txt` you would access the web dav server.

Comment: Then no. Just don't do this. It's a bad idea even if you can hack it to make it work.